# installing helix-p4d package on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management

I am trying to set up a helix core server for myself and a friend to work on. I want to get it running on a seperate PC I have laying around which runs ubuntu 20.04 but somehow I can't get the package to install.

I have completed all the steps described on the website (https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/install.linux.packages.install.html) but when I ultimately run `sudo apt-get install helix-p4d` the system tells me it is unable to locate the package.

Has anyone installed this package before? If so could you help me out or point out some things I might have overlooked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have missed some essential step. Open terminal and type:

```
wget -qO - https://package.perforce.com/perforce.pubkey | sudo apt-key add -

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/perforce.list
deb http://package.perforce.com/apt/ubuntu focal release
EOF

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install helix-p4d
```

---

Reference: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/install.linux.packages.install.html#For3

Comment: Thank you so much! this solved my issue.